# How to implement react navigation icon with step process

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-native

I have to create this sort of navigation. I have no idea what to call this and how should I implement this in Reactjs. Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Although it's an open-based question.

I'd like to declare the libs below:

- material-ui
- ant design
- bootstrap

---

The keyword is **step / stepper**

#### 1.material-ui [stepper](https://material-ui.com/components/steppers/)

[image]

#### 2.ant design [steps](https://ant.design/components/steps/)

[image]

#### 3.bootstrap [stepper](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/components/stepper/)

[image]

I'm sure you can find more libs to achieve this.